# What can I add to make small-gap privacy lattice more private?

Tags: fence, product-recommendation

A few months ago, I added some [privacy lattice](https://www.homedepot.com/p/Veranda-4-ft-x-8-ft-White-Privacy-Diamond-Vinyl-Lattice-Framed-73004042/100003591) to the top of my wooden fence. It's plastic lattice with 1.1 inch diamond-shaped holes. It's done a good job of making harder to see onto my deck/into my house, but it's still not perfect.

I would like to add something to the fence to make it more private, since it does not provide as much privacy as I would like. I thought I could use [fence weave/privacy tape](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B01FG8DHAU), but all I can find is ~2" wide tape. The holes in my lattice are 1.1", so I would need something much narrower.

I used a [faux ivy privacy fence cover](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B08F2LVCY3) on another privacy lattice I have, and it works very well, but that lattice has much larger holes and is therefore lighter. I am afraid to hang anything heavy on this lattice because it is already quite heavy and the fence supporting it is not that strong.

Any ideas as to what I could weave into/attach to the privacy lattice to cover up or fill in the holes?

Comment: Grow vines on the privacy lattice or plant larger bushes in front of it.

Comment: What about cutting the 2"  fence weave in half?

Comment: Yeah, seems like a straightedge and a utility knife would solve this in a hurry.

Answer (score 2):

You could use an agricultural fabric (stands up to sun - for a while) such as shade cloth or floating row cover.

Comment: Similarly dark nylon window screen is weather resistant.  You could do a test piece attaching the screen with a dab of hot glue thru the screen on to the vinyl.

Comment: That sounds like a stand-alone answer, @mikes!

Answer (score 2):

Take another piece of the same lattice and put the solid part over the 1 1/4 in. space…might work …go to the hardware store and do it there first with two pieces of lattice to see if it works.